# How to get nearest DateTime from 2 tables

Tags: sqlite, datetime

In SQLite, I want to build a query to get the nearest datetime for 'tag' entries against a 'tick' list:

```
CREATE TABLE Tick    (
     id integer primary key, 
     dt varchar(20) 
    );

INSERT INTO Tick (id, dt) VALUES 
( 1, '2018-10-30 13:00:00'), 
( 2, '2018-10-30 14:00:00'), 
( 3, '2018-10-30 15:00:00'), 
( 4, '2018-10-30 16:00:00'), 
( 5, '2018-10-30 17:00:00'), 
( 6, '2018-10-30 18:00:00'), 
( 7, '2018-10-30 19:00:00'), 
( 8, '2018-10-31 05:00:00'), 
( 9, '2018-10-31 06:00:00'), 
(10, '2018-10-31 07:00:00');


CREATE TABLE Tag    (
     id integer primary key, 
     dt varchar(20) 
    );

INSERT INTO Tag (id, dt) VALUES 
(100, '2018-10-30 16:08:00'), 
(101, '2018-10-30 17:30:00'), 
(102, '2018-10-30 19:12:00'), 
(103, '2018-10-31 04:00:00'), 
(104, '2018-10-31 13:00:00');
```

The following query gives me the good match (based on diff) but I'm unable to get Tick columns:

```
SELECT Tag.dt,
       (SELECT ABS(strftime('%s',Tick.dt) - strftime('%s',Tag.dt)) as diff
        FROM Tick
        ORDER BY diff ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as diff from Tag
```

I tried the following but I receive an error on Tag.dt in ORDER BY:

```
SELECT 
     Tag.id, Tag.dt,
     Tick.id, Tick.dt,
     abs(strftime('%s',Tick.dt) - strftime('%s',Tag.dt)) as Diff FROM Tag   JOIN Tick   ON Tick.dt =    (SELECT Tick.dt
    FROM Tick 
    ORDER BY abs(strftime('%s',Tick.dt) - strftime('%s',Tag.dt)) ASC
    limit 1)
```

The result I would like to have is something like:

```
TagID,DateTimeTag        ,TickID,DateTimeTick
    100,2018-10-30 16:08:00,     4,2018-10-30 16:00:00
    101,2018-10-30 17:30:00,     6,2018-10-30 18:00:00
    102,2018-10-30 19:12:00,     7,2018-10-30 19:00:00
    103,2018-10-31 04:00:00,     8,2018-10-31 05:00:00
    104,2018-10-31 13:00:00,    10,2018-10-31 07:00:00
```

Edited later... 
Based on [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas)'s answer, I was able to derive something without using the ROW_COUNTER() keyword which I can't use in FME.  I also set a maximum delta time difference (10000 sec) to find a match:

```
SELECT t.TagId, t.Tagdt, t.TickId, t.Tickdt, MIN(t.Diff)
FROM
(
SELECT 
     Tag.id as TagId, Tag.dt as Tagdt,
     Tick.id as TickId, Tick.dt as Tickdt,
     abs(strftime('%s',Tick.dt) - strftime('%s',Tag.dt)) as Diff
FROM Tag, Tick
WHERE Diff < 10000
) AS t
GROUP BY t.TagId
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my post with Fiddle schema.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Do you want to double-check those tagids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT t.tagID, t.tagDT, t.tickID, t.tickDT
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.tagID, t.tagDT ORDER BY t.Diff) AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT Tag.id tagID, Tag.dt tagDT, Tick.id tickID, Tick.dt tickDT,
      ABS(strftime('%s',Tick.dt) - strftime('%s',Tag.dt)) as Diff 
    FROM Tag CROSS JOIN Tick 
  ) AS t                                        
) AS t  
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/otnTpg7zKFSdkCb1WuAQMi/0).
Rsults:

```
| tagID | tagDT               | tickID | tickDT              |
| ----- | ------------------- | ------ | ------------------- |
| 100   | 2018-10-30 16:08:00 | 4      | 2018-10-30 16:00:00 |
| 101   | 2018-10-30 17:30:00 | 5      | 2018-10-30 17:00:00 |
| 102   | 2018-10-30 19:12:00 | 7      | 2018-10-30 19:00:00 |
| 103   | 2018-10-31 04:00:00 | 8      | 2018-10-31 05:00:00 |
| 104   | 2018-10-31 13:00:00 | 10     | 2018-10-31 07:00:00 |
```

Comment: It works, thanks for this piece of code.  Meanwhile for a strange reason, ROW_NUMBER is not accepted in FME SQL interpreter (as it is for SQL Fiddle).  Is it about a particular version or something like that?

Comment: Window functions were introduced for SQLite in version 3.25.0

Answer (score 0):

Create a `temp_table` query to get the differences of time stamps of the cross product of `Tick` and `Tag` tables and select the `min` value for each of the `Tick` table `id` s. 
The two temp_table queries are identical.
Note that this query may not be efficient as it takes full cross product across the two tables

```
SELECT temp_table.tid, temp_table.tdt, temp_table.tiid, temp_table.tidt, temp_table.diff
FROM
(SELECT Tag.id AS tid, Tag.dt AS tdt, Tick.id AS tiid, Tick.dt AS tidt, abs(strftime('%s',Tick.dt) - strftime('%s',Tag.dt)) as diff
FROM tag, tick) temp_table

WHERE temp_table.diff =

(SELECT MIN(temp_table2.diff) FROM
    (SELECT Tag.id AS tid, Tag.dt AS tdt, Tick.id AS tiid, Tick.dt AS tidt, abs(strftime('%s',Tick.dt) - strftime('%s',Tag.dt)) as diff
    FROM tag, tick) temp_table2
    WHERE temp_table2.tid = temp_table.tid
)

group by temp_table.tid
```